# Software Launcher creation tool?

Tags: windows, linux

I was making a little bundle of my favorite portable software. I've found an installer thing and stuff, but the only thing I'm missing is a launcher to launch the software in the bundle. Quick Menu Builder (quickmenubuilder.com) is a good idea but it doesn't quite have the features I need. Does anyone have alternatives to QMB? I was looking for an interface more like a setup wizard with radio buttons to choose what software you want. Note that I'm doing this on Windows not Linux. Also, I'd prefer a cross-platform menu, not Windows only as a lot of my friends use Linux. However, it doesn't need to be able to natively run in Linux, but it must be able to run natively in Windows. I would also like it to be free, but if not that's fine.